# Referencing modules in type declarations

Tags: typescript

How can I get a reference to another module in a module declaration? Please look at following example:

```javascript
declare module "meteor/meteor" {
  export module Meteor {
  ...
    enum StatusEnum {
      connected,
      connecting,
      failed,
      waiting,
      offline
    }
   ...
  }
}

declare module "meteor/ddp" {
  export module DDP {

    interface DDPStatus {
      ...
      status: Meteor.StatusEnum; // HOW DO I GET REFERENCE TO THE METEOR MODULE?
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // HOW DO I GET REFERENCE TO THE METEOR MODULE?

Just use an import like you normally would. :

```
declare module "meteor/ddp" {

  // Import
  import Meteor = require("meteor");

  export module DDP {

    interface DDPStatus {
      ...
      status: Meteor.StatusEnum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually it even worked with ES6 syntax: import Meteor from "meteor".

Comment: @tomitrescak you should probably have it as `import * as Meteor from "meteor"`  

Comment: One other thing. How do I do this in an application declaration file that does not belong to any module? I am a bit lost here.  e.g. I have an interface `declare interface IContext {
  Meteor: Meteor; }` how do I get reference to that Meteor? I'll ask another question. Will be cleaner.